# Problema com SESSION em php

Tags: php, mysql

Boas pessoal,

Estou aqui a desenvolver um login para a minha pagina mas estou com um problema em que nao me esta a guardar em sessão os dados que eu pretendo podem me dar uma ajuda.

Codigo

```
require_once("../gtm/bd/funcoes.php");
ligarBd();  

// Verifica se houve POST e se o usuário ou a senha é(são) vazio(s)
if (isset($_REQUEST['valida']) && $_REQUEST['valida']=="ok"){
    $sql="select * from users_social where fb_email='".$_REQUEST['user']."' and password='".sha1($_REQUEST['password'])."'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    if(mysql_num_rows($query)==1){
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
        session_register("user_id","nome", "user_foto");
        $_SESSION = array();
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['nome'] = $row['fb_nome'];
        $_SESSION['user_foto'] = $row['user_foto'];

        header("Location: http://sabeonde.pt/index.php");

    }
}

function ligarBd(){
    global $host, $bd, $user, $pass, $link;
    $link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Erro ao tentar abrir a base de dados". mysql_error());
    @mysql_select_db($bd);
}
```

Comment: Os dados bem da base dados

Comment: var_dum() realizado array(3) { ["user_id"]=> NULL ["nome"]=> NULL ["user_foto"]=> NULL

Comment: Desculpe a minha falta de atenção, César! É melhor fazer o `var_dump()` na variável `$row`.

Comment: Se possível, faça também na variável `$sql` para ter a certeza de que o query está a ser bem montado.

Comment: Você iniciou a sessão com `session_start` ?

Comment: sim iniciei session_start var_dum() na variável $row retorna NULL e variável $sql Retorna a query bem montada.

Comment: Neste caso, é melhor verificar se a conexão está a ser bem feita. Pode mostrar-nos o corpo da função `ligarBd()`?

Comment: Caso a conexão esteja OK, você pode verificar se uma query equivalente, quando executada directamente sobre a base de dados (sem o auxílio do PHP), retorna uma única linha?

Comment: Outra possibilidade é que o retorno da password criptografada esteja diferente do que está registrado na base de dados.

Comment: Ligação a base de dados esta ok pelo que testei verifiquei a query retornada no mysql e retorna uma linha correspondente a user que estava a efectuar login

Comment: colquei o corpo da funcao ligarbd() acima no post

Comment: `mysql_num_rows($query)` retorna 1?

Comment: mysql_num_rows($query) sim retorna 1

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

em vez de:

```
$row=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
```

Comment: +1 por ser mais rápido, hehe tava escrevendo isso como resposta :).

Comment: @rray Veja quanto tempo perdi fazendo perguntas nos comentários, hehehe. Às vezes, por falta de atenção, os problemas são mais simples de resolver do que achamos.

Comment: Eu tava olhando a pergunta antes e tbm n tinha notado xD rs. Nada que uma pausa para o café não resolva.

Comment: realmente estava mesmo a nossa frente obrigado pela ajuda realmente uma pausa para um café as vezes e melhor ehehe